# Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I am trying to create a Google Play Developers account but am unable to proceed any further as when I am on the Public Name screen, it states "To continue, fix errors". Anybody has faced this issue before and knows how to work around it? I am unable to send an email to Google as well as it somehow requires me to produce a Developers ID and App Bundle ID

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot or something

Comment: sorry for the delay, ive added the screenshot already

Comment: Maybe try a different browser or Clear cache & cookies

Comment: @AliAsjad thank you so much, i used chrome instead of safari and its working now

Comment: @deandrehaijiel if you find my comment helpful kindly upvote :)